# On Solutions of Diophantine Equation

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations

By *Mathematica*, I try to obtain solutions of Diophantine equations such as:

$$F_{n_1}F_{n_2}\cdots F_{n_k}+1=F_t$$

where the sequence $\{F_n\}$ is the Fibonacci sequence,$n_1 < n_2 < \cdots < n_k$ are positive integers, and $1 < t < 21$.

For example, one of the solutions is $F_2\times F_3+1=F_4$.

How can I find the solutions by *Mathematica*?

Comment: Do you want to count all combinations with `f[1]` and `f[2]` separately? That is, for any solution with `2<n1` there are three more solutions that also use `f[1]`, `f[2]` or `f[1]*f[2]`.

Comment: Yes, I want to obtain all solution of the diophantine equation including  `f[1] `and `f[2]` separately

Answer (score 3):

```
n       = 20;
ff      = Fibonacci /@ Range@n;
sus     = Subsets[Fibonacci /@ Range@n, {1, n}];
susf    = Subsets[f /@ Range@n, {1, n}];
results = 1 + Times @@@ sus;
e = Extract[susf, p = Position[results, x_?(MemberQ[ff, #] &)]]
```

These are the valid products:

```
(*{     
  {f[1]},
  {f[2]},
  {f[3]}, 
  {f[1], f[2]},
  {f[1], f[3]}, 
  {f[2], f[3]},
  {f[1], f[2], f[3]}}
 *)
```

To get the full  equations:

```
res = f /@ Flatten[Position[ff, #] & /@ Extract[results, p]]; 
Equal @@@ Transpose[{1 + Times @@@ e, res}] // Column

(*
1 + f[1] == f[3]
1 + f[2] == f[3]
1 + f[3] == f[4]
1 + f[1] f[2] == f[3]
1 + f[1] f[3] == f[4]
1 + f[2] f[3] == f[4]
1 + f[1] f[2] f[3] == f[4]
*)
```

Comment: Ah nice, I like the simplicity, but this is probably not feasible if you want to go much beyond the first 20 Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @MartinBüttner The number of `SetPartitions`  grows pretty fast too `f = (Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger[Fibonacci@# - 1]) & /@ 
   Range@100;
Max[BellB[Length /@ f]]`

Comment: Sure it's still a combinatorics problem. But the set partitions grow a lot slower than $2^n$ (mainly because the number of factors doesn't grow very fast). My solution solves up to $n = 50$ in a few seconds (and is dominated by a few numbers with many prime factors), whereas this approach will stop being feasible around $n = 30$.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yup. My  try was to find a simple way to solve the problem with `n = 20`, as stated. I don't pretend this approach to be scalable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a subset sum approach using lattice reduction. For this we work with logs, scaled up and rounded to get an integer lattice. It's not guaranteed to find a solution but in practice it seems quite good at finding near misses wherein a quotient of such products "almost" works.

```
fibProd[n_Integer] := Catch[Module[
   {fibs = Fibonacci[Range[3, n - 1]], fiblogs, 
    fm1log = Log[Fibonacci[n] - 1], rlogs, lat, redlat, row},
   fiblogs = Log[fibs];
   rlogs = Round[2^20*Append[fiblogs, fm1log]];
   lat = Join[Transpose[{rlogs}], IdentityMatrix[n - 2], 2];
   lat[[-1, -1]] = 2^10;
   lat = LatticeReduce[lat];
   If[Length[Select[lat, Abs[Last[#]] == 2^10 &]] > 1, 
    Print[{"found more", n}]];
   row = SelectFirst[lat, Abs[Last[#]] == 2^10 &];
   If[! FreeQ[row, Missing], Throw[$Failed]];
       row = row[[2 ;; -2]];
       If[Max[Abs[row]] > 1, Throw[$Failed]];
   1/fibs^row
   ]]
```

Running it to 220 produced only the trivial result fib(2)+1=fib(3).

Answer (score 1):

This answer currently ignores solutions involving `f[1]` and `f[2]`, because they are trivial to find by hand:

```
f[1] + 1 = f[3]
f[2] + 1 = f[3]
f[1]*f[2] + 1 = f[3]
```

Additionally, by prepending these three factors to any other solution you can get three more solutions. E.g. if you have `f[3] + 1 = f[4]`, then 3 more solutions are:

```
f[1]*f[3] + 1 = f[4]
f[2]*f[3] + 1 = f[4]
f[1]*f[2]*f[3] + 1 = f[4]
```

In fact, it appears that these 6 are the only solutions up to $F_{50}$ (unless I made a mistake, of course).

I first tried putting a system of equations into `FindInstance`, but it's incredibly slow. Instead, it's much easier here to look for possible solutions manually, by checking in how many ways we can express starting from $F_t-1$ as a product of distinct Fibonacci numbers:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"];
maxN = 21;
(* Lookup table of admissible Fibonacci numbers. *)
fibs = Fibonacci@Range@maxN
solutions = {};
For[n = 4, n < maxN, ++n,
  (* Get the list of (F_n-1)'s prime factors. *)
  factors = Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger[Fibonacci@n - 1];
  (* Now we get all, not necessarily contiguous partitions of the factors from
     which we reconstruct all possible decompositions into factors of F_n-1. *)
  decompositions = Union[Sort /@ (Times @@@ # & /@ SetPartitions[factors])];
  (* We retain only those decompositions that contain only distinct numbers, all
     of which have to be Fibonacci numbers, and append them to the solutions. *)
  solutions = Join[
   solutions, {#, Fibonacci@n} & /@ 
    Select[decompositions, 
     AllTrue[#, MemberQ[fibs, #] &] && Unequal @@ # &]]
  ];
solutions
(* {{{2}, 3}} *)
```

I admit there's a lot of syntactic sugar in there, so let me know if anything is unclear.